# design view in vs2013 does not show anything

Tags: c#, asp.net

in vs 2013 trying to open the design view on the pages that i have been working on and all i get is a blank page, I have tried changing the open with and setting it to default so that i can open which has not worked.. but when i run in browser the pages shows perferctly
[image]
but every time i try open with design view all i get is a blank page... anybody have an idea what is going on here???

note ignore this peice of code:

```
rotected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = functions.login(TxtUserName.Text, TxtPassword.Text);
            LabelMessage.Text = result;
        }
```

Comment: Copy the page to the desktop. Remove from solution. Clean and build your solution. Then add your page again.

Comment: Did that and did not work